# Assigning property with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex

Let's say we retrieve contact list from server with next page:

```
retrieveContacts()
    .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] contacts, nextPage in 
        self?.nextPage = nextPage
        // do something with contacts
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Now we want to pass these contacts to other observables, but in meantime we have to assign `self.nextPage` to new `nextPage`. We can do it on the background like this:

```
retrieveContacts()
        .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .map { [weak self] contacts, nextPage in 
            self?.nextPage = nextPage
            return Observable.just(contacts)
        }
        .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
        .map { contacts in
            // do something with contacts but now on background
        }
```

Is there any better way to assign property by changing the thread in `.observeOn` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
let observable = retrieveContacts()
    .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    .share()

    observable.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] contacts, nextPage in 
        self?.nextPage = nextPage
        // do something with nextPage
    })

    observable.observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] contacts, nextPage in 
        self?.contacts = contacts
        // do something with contacts
    })
```